# how to apply a bevel modifier for sharp edges from a rig

Tags: rigging, bevel

[image]I have a simple rig that works great for animating opening and closing a box based on this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKyeutvRt24).

Is it possible to add an edge bevel modifier when there are sharp edges from a rig?

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "sharp edges from a rig"? Please show some pictures. I guess you can add a bevel modifier without problem

Comment: when I create a mesh (for example a basic cube) I can easily add an edge bevel modifier that smoothes out the edges. when I create a cube from the tutorial linked above by rigging a flattened die-cut it also creates sharp edges from the folds that we'd like to bevel

Comment: maybe put the Bevel modifier before the Armature modifier? If it doesn't work show some pictures or even share your file

Comment: as moonboots commented, yes you can:  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbl8U.gif

Comment: not sure how to share a file but I've added a screenshot

Comment: Sure you can. See [this video](https://youtu.be/O1em_ijMvUk) posted on YT 5 days ago.

Comment: thank you everyone -- all your comments and links really helped. after spending all day and looking online for bevel issues I got it to work by turning off "clamp overlap". for whatever reason it bevels fine when I manually fold the edges but if I use the rig to fold the edges I need to turn off "clamp overlap" to get it to bevel